# Flash AS3 count capital letters?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash

How could I count the number of capital letters in a string using flash as3?

for example

```
var thestring = "This is The String";
```

should return int 3

Thank you

Comment: I don't know that regex is the best way to go here you may be better off just looping through the characters in the string and seeing if they fit in the ASCII range for upper case characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// Starting string.
var thestring:String = "This is The String";

// Match all capital letters and check the length of the returned match array.
var caps:int = thestring.match(/[A-Z]/g).length;
trace(caps); // 3
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to convert the string to lower case and count the characters affected. That means you don't have to specify which characters to include in the category of "uppercase letters", which isn't trivial. This method supports accented characters such as É.

```
// Starting string.
var theString:String = "'Ö' is actually the Swedish word for 'island'";

var lowerCase : String = theString.toLowerCase();
var upperCount : int = 0;

for (var i:int = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
    if (theString.charAt(i) != lowerCase.charAt(i)) {
        upperCount++;
    }
}

trace(upperCount); // prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Each letter in a string has a value that corresponds with that letter:

```
var myString:String = "azAZ";
trace(myString.charCodeAt(0));
trace(myString.charCodeAt(1));
trace(myString.charCodeAt(2));
trace(myString.charCodeAt(3));

// Output is 97, 122, 65, 90
```

The name.charCodeAt(x) returns the code of the letter at the position in the string, starting at 0.

From this output we know that a - z are values ranging from 97 to 122, and we also know, that A - Z are values ranging from 65 - 90.

With that, we can now make a For Loop to find capital letters:

```
var myString:String = "This is The String";
var tally:int = 0;


for (var i:int = 0; i < myString.length; i++)
{
    if (myString.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && myString.charCodeAt(i) <= 95)
    {
        tally += 1;
    }
}

trace(tally);
// Output is 3.
```

The variable "tally" is used to keep track of the number of capital letters found. In the For Loop, we are seeing if the value of the current letter it is analyzing is between the values 65 and 90. If it is, it adds 1 to tally and then traces the total amount when the For Loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Why be succint?  I say, processing power is made to be used.  So:

```
const VALUE_0:uint = 0;
const VALUE_1:uint = 1;

var ltrs:String = "This is JUST some random TexT.  How many Caps?";

var cnt:int = 0;

for(var i:int = 0; i < ltrs.length; i++){
    cnt += processLetter(ltrs.substr(i,1));
}

trace("Total capital letters: " + cnt);

function processLetter(char:String):int{
    var asc:int = char.charCodeAt(0);
    if(asc >= Keyboard.A && asc <= Keyboard.Z){
        return VALUE_1;
    }
    return VALUE_0;
}

// Heh heh!
```